# need dotnet core 2.1 to show up in visual studio

Tags: asp.net-core

When I try to upgrade ASP.NET Core in Nuget package manager, I get the following error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.0-preview2-final is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.0-preview2-final supports: netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1)         0

I have installed the sdk multiple times, so I'm confused because when I go to target it only has up to dotnet core 2.0 as an option. I installed visual studio preview but that hasn't helped either. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

For .NET Core 2.1 you need (currently) version 2.1.300-rc1 of the sdk. The version numbers of the SDK and .NET Core are not in sync, older 2.1 versions of the SDK are not enough.

This version can be downloaded from here: https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/dotnet-core/sdk-2.1.300-rc1

You can check the version on command line with `donet --version` command. `dotnet --info` will also list all the installed runtimes and SDKs.

```
   > dotnet --version
   2.1.300-rc1-008673
```

Comment: Is this something that will resolve itself if I just wait a few days or weeks?  I'm creating my first ASP.NET Core API service, and after I got the initial scaffolded project I tried to update the one-and-only NuGet package (the scaffold only gives me Microsoft.AspNetCore.All v2.0.8).  I see that this question is a month old, so maybe waiting isn't such a good option?

Comment: Oh... I followed the link to the sdk-2.1.300-rc1 download page, and it says I need a preview version of Visual Studio 2017.  So now I'm confused. `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All v2.1.0` is offered to me as a NuGet update, but I can't really get it in my current (production) version of Visual Studio 2017?